# Suddenly Unable to Scrape Data from ADVFN

Tags: r, quantmod

No changes to my code or system, but as of last week:

```
fund.data('NVDA',80,'quarterly')
```

Returns:

```
Downloading http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=financials&symbol=NVDA&?btn=quarterly_reports
No Data Found for NVDA 
NULL
```

Any idea on what is happening?

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using SIT (https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/blob/master/R/fundamental.data.r). The "fund.data" command is a standalone function with this tool, and I only load quantmod prior to running this in the past. Can you replicate this error?

Comment: My guess is that the HTML of the site changed, so the function needs to be updated to account for the changes.